# strange error cannot resolve <folder name> in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have below code structure, 
[image]

and my src/components/App.js look like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { max_number } from '../helper'

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

As you can see helper folder is the same level as components, but somehow I got error of Module not found: Can't resolve `'../helper' in '/Users/james/Documents/react-demo/src/components'`

Comment: Looks like `helper.js` is a *directory* and not a JavaScript source file.

Comment: You need to import like `import { max_number } from '../helper.js'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`helper.js` is a directory you need to import from `'../helper.js'`

preferably rename the folder to `helper`